# How to set default checked radio button in nopcommerce 4.3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, nopcommerce, checked

I want to check bydefault one radiobutton from three option in nopcommerce 4.3

Here is my code,

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="raw">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    @Html.RadioButton("LabourChargeUnit", "false", (Model.LabourChargeUnit == "PCS"), new { id = "LabourChargeUnit_PCS"})
                    @T("Admin.Catalog.Product.Fields.LabourChargeUnit.PCS")
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    @Html.RadioButton("LabourChargeUnit", "false", (Model.LabourChargeUnit == "PER"), new { id = "LabourChargeUnit_PER" })
                    @T("Admin.Catalog.Product.Fields.LabourChargeUnit.PER")
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    @Html.RadioButton("LabourChargeUnit", "true", (Model.LabourChargeUnit == "GM"), new { id = "LabourChargeUnit_GM" })
                    @T("Admin.Catalog.Product.Fields.LabourChargeUnit.GM")
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have tried many things like **new{@checked = "checked"}, true/false, 0/1** but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of example in the nopCommerce4.3 source. You can take a look at Presentation==>Nop.Web==>Views==>Customer==>Register.cshtml and see the below code

```
<div class="gender">
    <p class="mb-1 d-inline-block">
       <input type="radio" asp-for="Gender" value="M" checked="@(Model.Gender == "M")" id="gender-male" />
       <label class="forcheckbox mr-1 d-block text-left" for="gender-male">
            <span class="">  @T("Account.Fields.Gender.Male") </span>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p class="mb-1 d-inline-block">
          <input type="radio" asp-for="Gender" value="F" checked="@(Model.Gender == "F")" id="gender-female" />
             <label class="gender-female text-left" for="gender-female">
                <span class=""> @T("Account.Fields.Gender.Female") </span>
            </label>
      </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@T("Account.Fields.Gender.Male") 
        
      
      
          
             
                 @T("Account.Fields.Gender.Female")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).